# I need Update or Insert functionality in Kafka JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

[Kafka JDBC Sink Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZIKt.png)

Kafka JDBC sink connector provide 3 insert.mode ..but i need update or insert functionality  together . Anyone help how to achieve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`upsert` literally means both insert or update for existing keys that have already been inserted

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following steps:

1. separation events among 2 topics on source connector (topic for inserts and topic for updates)
2. procesing thee topics with independent sink connectors with different configurations.